# How to set up output files based on key names?

Tags: java, hadoop

How do I set up output files based on key names?

For example, take the popular WordCount example in mapreduce. If I give it an arbitrary file with the correct syntax it should find keys (words) and the frequency of their appearances. How do I get an output where each key is the filename and inside the file is the value?

(I'm asking because my current understanding is that MultipleOutputs still need to specify a specific filename to use)

Using hadoop 0.20.205.0

(Also can someone point me to some good tutorials for this hadoop version?)

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [this function](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28KEYOUT,%20VALUEOUT,%20java.lang.String%29) in [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28KEYOUT,%20VALUEOUT,%20java.lang.String%29) you don't need to pre-sepecify the file names anywhere when initializing the job.

Use this from the reducer -

```
void write(K key, V value, String baseOutputPath);
```

baseOutputPath can be the string representation of your key.

e.g.  `void write(K key, V value, getFileName(key))`

```
getFileName(K key){
   return (key.toString());
}
```

Please have a look at the examples in the links, you'll get the idea.

Moreover, you don't need to user `context.write()` from the reducer. But rather use the 
MultipleOuputs' `write()` function only.

That makes everything dynamic, in my view, if that's what you want.

**NOTE (after comment):**

Since, you said you cannot use the MultipleOutputs, the is another way you can actually to 
that.

1. Since a reduce function deal with only one key, instead of doing a context.write(key, value) you can use Hadoop [FileSystem api](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to create a file (with your key name) in HDFS.

Something like:

```
 FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
 FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(key.toString());
```

1. [create()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20int%29) function would return you a FSDataOutputStream object. Use the write() function to write to the file.
2. Close the FileSystem object after you are done.
   Something like - `fs.close();`

Comment: don't think I can use this in 0.20.205.0

Comment: @Julian: I have updated my answer accordingly, that should support Hadoop 0.20.205 if you are not planning to create a MultipleOutputs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to write values to multiple files based on different keys, simply use the keys (`String`s, I would presume) to construct the file names and create the files in the usual way, e.g., with [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: ah so hadoop's output doesn't always have to be the resulting files I want? I can just write it with filewriter? awesome. What's the point of hadoop's output then?

Comment: also anyway to get the path in the reducer then?